# zip multiple files and send as mail in a single command in linux

Tags: email-attachments

Can we zip multiple text files and send as mail in a single linux command? I tried something with `uuencode`, but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use

```
tar cz *.txt | uuencode tarball.tgz - | mail -s "The text files you requested" target@destination.com
```

If i'm not wrong, 7z has a method to create zipfiles directly to stdout, much like the tar command shown

Comment: i tried the command you use, and i got the following error..      $ tar cz *.log | uuencode cronlogsformail.tgz - | mail -s "cronjob execution log" sanand@indavest.com
uuencode: fopen-ing cronlogsformail.tgz: Unknown system error
Null message body; hope that's ok